# How to search inside a MS-Access Database Table using VB6?

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, ado

I'm using VB6 for a school project and I want make a library management system with databases using Access. The ADODC and DataGrid are working fine and I can add new entries and delete them as well. But what if I want to search a particular item according to a field. I cannot seem to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `Form` where you placed your `DataGrid` and your `ADODataControl`.

On the *Toolbox*, double click the *TextBox icon* to add a `TextBox` to the Form.

On the Toolbox, double click the *Label icon* to add a `Label` to the Form.

Double click the `TextBox` to open the code editor window, and inside `Text1_Change()` event add this piece of code (assuming here your `ADODataControl`  is called *Adodc1* and the `Field` where you need to search is called *Title*) :

```
If Text1.Text > "" Then
    Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = "Title Like '*" & Replace(Text1.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
Else
    Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = adFilterNone
    Adodc1.Recordset.Requery
End If
```

On the top of the same code editor window, on the **left side**, select your `ADODataControl`, and on the **right side** select `MoveComplete`.

Add this piece of code inside the `MoveComplete` event:

```
Label1.Caption = "Records: " & pRecordset.RecordCount
```

That's all. 
Your Form should looks and behave like in the picture below (if this is not the case, I am sorry, but you haven't provided enough detail in your question):

[image]

This example was built by using the Biblio.mdb database delivered with VB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
        With Datagrid
                varBookmark = .Bookmark
            If (.SelBookmarks.Count <> 0) Then
                .SelBookmarks.Remove 0
            End If
                Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst
                Adodc1.Recordset.Find "[Name of column you want to search] like '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
            If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF Or Adodc1.Recordset.BOF Then
                MsgBox "No Student Found.", vbInformation, "Error"
                Adodc1.Recordset.Bookmark = varBookmark
            Else
                MsgBox "Student found Successfully", vbInformation, "Success"
                .SelBookmarks.Add Adodc1.Recordset.Bookmark
                Me.Hide
            End If
        End With
```

Change the Datagrid name at the top to the name of the datagrid you are using and the adodc as well.